# Using Macbook's internal mic while closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

When I close the lid of my new macbook (Pro 2021) with macOS 12, the internal mic stops recording *any* sound, not even muffling the noise coming at it - despite apparently not being muted, and remaining selected as the input device in the Sound settings.

Is there a way restore the old behaviour (MacbookPro 2013), so I can use the internal mic while closed and docked (using external monitor/keyboard/headphones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Apple Silicon-based Mac notebooks and Intel-based Mac notebooks with the Apple T2 Security Chip feature a hardware disconnect that disables the microphone whenever the lid is closed. (Apple Support: [Hardware microphone disconnect](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/hardware-microphone-disconnect-secbbd20b00b/web))

The feature was first introduced to Macs by way of Apple’s T2 security chip last year. The security chip ensured that the microphone was physically disconnected from the device when the user shuts their MacBook lid.
(Techcrunch article: [Apple brings its hardware microphone disconnect feature to iPads](https://techcrunch.com/2020/04/03/apple-hardware-microphone-disconnect-ipads/))